# login function with php mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a login function with php.

Till now this is what I got.

```
<?php
include("dbconnection.php");
//select a database to work with
$mysqli->select_db("eamunter_opskrift");
Echo ("Selected the eamunter_opskrift database...<BR><BR>");
// get the username and password from the login form
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

//Protect username and password
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$query ="SELECT * FROM brugerregistration WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $username and $password, the count of table rows should equal 1
if($count==1){
// Register session variables and redirect the user to "login_success.php" page
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']= $username;
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

I keep getting the same error
And I can't figure out what the problem is... My dbconnection.php works everywhere else.

```
Selected the eamunter_opskrift database...

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock) in /home/www/.dk/reg/post_login.php on line 13

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: No such file or directory in /home/www/.dk/reg/post_login.php on line 13

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/www/.dk/reg/post_login.php on line 13

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock) in /home/www/.dk/reg/post_login.php on line 14

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: No such file or directory in /home/www/.dk/reg/post_login.php on line 14

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/www/.dk/reg/post_login.php on line 14

Wrong Username or Password
```

Can anybody help me???

If important I can upload the form too, but didn't think it mattered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `mysql_real_escape_string` with `$mysqli->real_escape_string`

(Also, you don't need the `stripslashes` calls, `real_escape_string` should do all that for you)

Comment: Cool thanks :-)
Do you know why it keeps writing `post_login.php?username=user&password=1234&Submit=Login` at the end of the link. Not very clever to have the password in the link...

Comment: Likely because your `<form`> action would have been set to GET instead of POST.

Comment: In your HTML form, add `method="post"` so it reads `<form method="post"`. That'll stop that showing up :) x

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.

It should be

```
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);
```

Comment: Thanks didn't notice. Now I just need to get it to work with the database :-) Only getting `Selected the eamunter_opskrift database...
Wrong Username or Password` now.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
<?php
    include("dbconnection.php");
    //select a database to work with
    $mysqli->select_db("eamunter_opskrift");
    Echo ("Selected the eamunter_opskrift database...<BR><BR>");
    // get the username and password from the login form
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    //You should use your object and current connection 
    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);

    $query ="SELECT * FROM brugerregistration WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $username and $password, the count of table rows should equal 1
    if($count==1){
    // Register session variables and redirect the user to "login_success.php" page
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username']= $username;
    header("location:login_success.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

see the doc of [**`mysql_real_escape_string`**](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

replace :

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

by :

```
$username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
$password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);
```